# Images and text are not fading in and BG color of navbar not changing when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, css, navbar, background-color, fadein

This code was working properly before adding JS for fading in elements (images and text) for my service section. Now both the code are not working. Can you please help me out with both the problem

```
    //NAVBAR
    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
      function scrollFunction() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
                document.getElementById("navbar").style.background = "black" ;
          }
    else{
               document.getElementById("navbar").style.background = "transparent";
         }

    }
```

**After adding this JS** for my fade in for the images the background color of navbar does not change when i scroll down.
Even this code is not working properly the images are not fading in as expected. Please check what is the mistake i have done

```
      //SERVICES SECTION

     const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-in");
     const fader = documnet.querySelectorAll(".fade-in");
     const appearOptions = { threshold: 10, rootMargin: "0px 0px -100px 0px"  };
     const appearOnScroll1 = new IntersectionObserver(
         function(entries,appearOnScroll)
           {
              entries.forEach(entry=>{
               if(!entry.isIntersecting){
                    return;
                 }
        else{
                 entry.target.classList.add('appear');
                appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
            }
     });
     },
     appearOptions;

     fader.forEach(fader=>{
     appearOnScroll.observe(fader);
     });
     sliders.forEach(slider=>{
     appearOnScroll.observe(sliders);
     });
    );
```

This my CSS for service section

````
     #service-container{ 
     /* margin: 15px 43px; */
     display: grid;
     /* grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr; */
     padding: 30px;
     width: 96%;
     height: 100%;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgb(255, 255, 255),rgb(226, 162, 
     194),rgb(196, 113, 154),rgb(248, 138, 193));
     z-index: -1;
    }
    #service-container .h-primary2{ 
     margin: 15px 43px;
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:900;
    }
    #services{
     font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    }
    .columns img{
      /* display: grid; */
     width: 50%;
     height: 50%;
     /* margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto; */
    }

    div #h-secondary{ 
     text-align: center;
      
    }
    div .from-right{
     /* display: grid; */
     float: right; 
     text-align: center;
     grid-column: 3/4;
     transform: translateX(50%);
    }

    div .from-left{
     /* display: grid; */
     float: left;
     text-align: center;
     grid-column: 2/3;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
   
    }

    .from-left, .from-right{
     opacity: 250ms ease-in;
      transform: 400ms ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
    }
    .from-left .appear, .from-right .appear{
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;   
    }
      
    body{
        margin: 0;
        /* overflow: hidden; */
    }

    .fade-in{
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 250ms ease-in;
    }
    .fade-in .appear{
        opacity: 1;
    }     
    ```
````

Comment: here is a github repo https://github.com/john-smilga/javascript-basic-projects/tree/master/10-scroll/final

Comment: return doesn't stop a forEach. Why are you testing 'document.documentElement.scrollTop'   ? Doesn't seem to be necessary.